# Django: Best way to handle multiselect US state selection

Tags: django

What is the best way to include in a model to save multi-select US states? I need a user to select several states and save this data in a model (via form OR modelform ).

I tried [LocalFlavor USStateField model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#django.contrib.localflavor.us.models.USStateField) it doesn't seem to work for me since I can't call it like a regular model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/thikonom/django_countries_states) django app i've written may help you.